# Achievements screen's "Done" button not working on some devices

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uikit, game-center

I'm using GKAchievementViewController to display achievements. It works fine on most devices, but on some (iPod Touch 3rd Gen and iPad 1 running iOS 5.1.1) taping the Done button does nothing.

I have no idea how to debug this...

Here is the code I'm using to display the achievements:

```
    viewController = [[GKAchievementViewController alloc] init];
    if (viewController)
    {
        viewController.achievementDelegate = self;

        [self presentModalViewController:viewController animated:YES];
    }
```

and then:

```
- (void)achievementViewControllerDidFinish:(GKAchievementViewController *)aViewController
{
     [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question in case anyone has the same problem.
This seems to have solved the issue:

```
- (void)achievementViewControllerDidFinish:(GKAchievementViewController *)aViewController
{
        if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion:)])
        {
            [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
                aViewController.achievementDelegate = nil;
                [aViewController release];
            }];
        }
        else
        {
            [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
            aViewController.achievementDelegate = nil;
            [aViewController release];
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Should work when implementing `achievementViewControllerDidFinish:`

```
- (void) achievementViewControllerDidFinish:(GKAchievementViewController *)viewController
{
    [viewController.delegate dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Comment: But this is not a Leaderboard view controller. Does it still work for Achievement controllers?

Comment: Oh, did you mean achievementViewControllerDidFinish? I'm already implementing it. I'll update the question

Comment: Sorry, was distracted. You should call that dismiss on the parent viewController for older OS's.